# Get AlertDialog selected Item

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How do you get the selected item text from an AlertDialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsCustom.this);
b.setTitle("Example");
String[] types = {"Item 1","Item 2","Item 3" };
b.setItems(types, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
        dialogInterface.dismiss();

        //How to get the selected text
    }
});

b.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a way. But don't know if it's the best way.

```
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsCustom.this);
b.setTitle("Example");
final String[] types = {"Item 1","Item 2","Item 3" };
b.setItems(types, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
        dialogInterface.dismiss();

        //How to get the selected text
        Log.v("-----> " , "selected text = " + types[which]);
    }
});

b.show();
```

Comment: Yes, it's the only way. OnClickListener is **intended** to get `which` and use it further

Answer (score 0):

You need to register for DialogInterface.OnClickListener and use setPostivie, setsinglechoice, setmultichoice etc. methods.